How can I handle 'Time out waiting for response'?
I recently moved an application from the Elastic Beanstalk to EKS and facing an occasional error of Timed out waiting for response.
The TcpNetClientConnectionFactory is produced like this.
  @Bean
  public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientCF() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(clientHost, clientPort);
    cf.setSerializer(new ByteArrayLengthStringHeaderSerializer());
    cf.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayLengthStringHeaderSerializer());
    return cf;
  }

And the MessageHandler is defined like this.
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "TcpOut")
  public MessageHandler tcpOutGateway(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf) {
    TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    gateway.setRequestTimeout(requestTimeout); // 60000
    gateway.setRemoteTimeout(remoteTimeout);   // 60000
    gateway.setOutputChannelName("toTransformer");
    return gateway;
  }

I'm facing

a couple of Timed out waiting for response
eventually, a Socket closed exception

And the place throws the error seems to be here.
// TcpOutboundGateway.java

            AsyncReply reply = new AsyncReply(remoteTimeout);
            connectionId = connection.getConnectionId();
            this.pendingReplies.put(connectionId, reply);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Added pending reply " + connectionId);
            }
            connection.send(requestMessage);
            Message<?> replyMessage = reply.getReply();
            if (replyMessage == null) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Remote Timeout on " + connectionId);
                }
                // The connection is dirty - force it closed.
                this.connectionFactory.forceClose(connection);
                throw new MessageTimeoutException(requestMessage, "Timed out waiting for response");
            }
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Response " + replyMessage);
            }
            return replyMessage;

What does the The connection is dirty - force it closed. mean?
How can I fix this? Thanks

We don't know what is that ByteArrayLengthStringHeaderSerializer, but this is really crucial to communicate with the server. You need to agree a request-reply contract between your client and server. Apparently your server cannot answer to your client somehow. Even that 60000 does not help you. So, the problem is somewhere else on the server side or your client does not expect whatever server answers (if ever).
